# Lucene indexes in Neo4j don't work as expected

Tags: lucene, neo4j

I think that the title is a little bit vague, so I'm going to explain precisely my problem.

I am creating some nodes in Neo4j and then index them like this :

```
Index<Node> myindex = graphDb.index().forNodes(
                "myindex",
                MapUtil.stringMap(IndexManager.PROVIDER, "lucene", "type",
                        "fulltext"));

Node n = graphDb.createNode(); //create the node
node.setProperty("firstname", "firstname"); //add properties
node.setProperty("familyname", "familyname");
myindex.add(node, "familyname", "familyname"); //index it
```

But when I need to update Node "n" 's properties (for instance change "familyname" to "fname"), this node can't be found anymore through an index based search!

So before updating the property, this cypher query

`start n= node:myindex(familyname:"familyname") return n`
 was returning the Node, whereas after update, I am expecting :

`start n= node:myindex(familyname:"fname") return n`

to return the same node with the new property, but it doesn't work ! While the first query is always working, like if the index is bound to the property "familyname"

Any thoughts about this ?

Thanks

Comment: You should update the index as well (first remove, then add).

Comment: Will try it right now !

Comment: You are right ! 
Actually, I thought that the index was bound to the Node and the property chosen . Thanks

Comment: No, as far as I know it does not work _automagically_. ;-)

Comment: This is exactly where spring-data-neo4j can help you with. All of this scaffolding is taken care for you. If you want you can give it a try http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j

Comment: Your idea is interesting, but I am currently writing my code in Python/Django and was just trying to figure out what is happening with some java code :) 
Thanks for your proposition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as `tstorms` suggested, the solution is to remove the index after updating the property :

```
n.setProperty("familyname","fname");
myindex.remove(n);
```

then add it with the new property :

```
myindex.add(n, "familyname","fname");
```

Comment: I can't do so because I am using some specific indexes to sort my elements in the db. For example: entities Person, School, Company have each an index on them

Comment: Also, look at Neo4j 2.0 Label support with transparent indexing, which doesn't have these problems, http://www.neo4j.org/develop/labels